# APNS production certificate not working

Tags: java, javaapns

i am new bie in push notification and trying to apns push notification but it not working.

my code is

```
    ApnsService service = APNS.newService()
            .withCert(apns_keystore, apns_keystore_password)
            .withProductionDestination().build();
    String payload = APNS.newPayload().badge((int) badge)
            .alertBody(body).sound("chime").actionKey(from).build();
    service.push(token, payload);
```

please help me

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: development is fine but in production i am not getting notification